# Why does having an assignment of a variable outside of my while loop affect my method's behavior?

Tags: ruby

I am currently learning Ruby, and going through a few practice problems. I have been tasked with the following:

> Write a method that takes input as a string. Your method should return the most common letter in the array and a count of how many times it appears.

This is what I came up with:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  x = 0
  holder = string[x]
  topcount = 0
  topstring = 0
  while string.length > x
    counter = 0
    y = 0
    while string.length > y
      if holder == string[y]
        counter += 1
      end
        y += 1  
      if topcount == 0 || counter > topcount
        topcount = counter
        topstring = holder
       end
    end
    x += 1
  end
  return [topstring, topcount]
end
```

It returns the first value it finds but the correct amount of topcounts. For the life of me, I can't figure out why after stepping through my code, but it's obvious I'm missing a glaring mistake!!

After looking at the solution the only difference between what I've proposed and the solution was this:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  x = 0
  topcount = 0
  topstring = 0
  while string.length > x
    holder = string[x]
    counter = 0
    y = 0
    while string.length > y
      if holder == string[y]
        counter += 1
      end
        y += 1  
      if topcount == 0 || counter > topcount
        topcount = counter
        topstring = holder
       end
    end
    x += 1
  end
  return [topstring, topcount]
end
```

Why does moving the assignment inside the while loop affect the behavior if x is still being reassigned outside of the loop??

The answer must be right in front of me but I don't know why!!

Comment: You need to move it inside of the loop so that it updates at each iteration. Otherwise, it will stay with the first value assigned (the first letter in the string)

Comment: I realize this wasn't part of your question, but this particular problem can be solved with a one-liner: `string.chars.group_by{|x| x}.map{|char, occurrences| [char, occurrences.count]}.sort_by{|_, num_occurances| num_occurances}.last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it becomes clear if you remove some lines:

```
def inside(string)
  x = 0
  while string.length > x
    holder = string[x]
    puts holder
    x += 1
  end
end

inside('abc')
```

Here, `holder` is set three times within the loop, using the current value of `x`, i.e. `0`, `1` and `2`.

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

And the other one:

```
def outside(string)
  x = 0
  holder = string[x]
  while string.length > x
    puts holder
    x += 1
  end
end

outside('abc')
```

Here, `holder` is set once outside the loop, using the initial value of `x`, i.e. `0`.

Output:

```
a
a
a
```

Comment: Oh wow, I think I really failed to realize that x += 1 is really just x = x + 1 and therefore x is being reassigned within the loop and therefore holder does not update. For some reason somewhere in my mind x += 1 was reassigning x from outside of the loop while in reality it is what I specified above.

Thanks Stefan!! 

Sometimes I feel like I am forgetting the most basic understanding of code...